# Remove empty first column of a Treeview object

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm trying to make a program that retrieves records from a database using `sqlite3`, and then display them using a `Treeview`.

I succeeded in having a table created with the records, but I just can't remove the first empty column.

```
def executethiscommand(search_str):
    comm.execute(search_str)
    records = comm.fetchall()
    rows = records.__len__()
    columns = records[0].__len__()

    win = Toplevel()
    list_columns = [columnames[0] for columnames in comm.description]
    tree = ttk.Treeview(win)
    tree['columns'] = list_columns

    for column in list_columns:
        tree.column(column, width=70)
        tree.heading(column, text=column.capitalize())

    for record in records:
        tree.insert("", 0, text="", values=record)

    tree.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
```

[image]

Answer (score 38):

That first empty column is the identifier of the item, you can suppress that by setting the show parameter.

```
t = ttk.Treeview(w)
t['show'] = 'headings'
```

That will eliminate that empty column.

Answer (score 10):

A little bit late and hacky but what you also could do is:

```
tree.column("#0", width=0)
```

not forgetting to set the minimum width too to zero by using;
tree.column("#0", minwidth="0")

'#0' is the identifier of the first column, so setting the width to 0 would technically hide it

Comment: This does not work, at least for me. It still shows an empty small column, as if there was a minimum width implied by that command.

Comment: right, this doesn't work, however adding minwidth=0 solved the issue of default minwidth.

Comment: Did not work for me even with the minwidth=0. Still a small column is shown

Comment: try `tree.column("#0", width = 0, stretch = "no")` @Youstanzr

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want to use something like a [TkTable](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTable) better than a TreeView.
In TreeView, the first column is defined for giving a name or id to the object described in each row. From the [docs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html):

> A treeview widget can display and allow browsing through a hierarchy
>   of items, and can show one or more attributes of each item as columns
>   to the right of the tree.

You fill the first column with:

```
tree.insert('', insert_mode, text='name first col')
```

If you still want to use the first column as a normal column you could try:

```
tree['columns'] = list_columns[1:]
for record in records:
    tree.insert("", 0, text=record[0], values=record[1:])
```

However I dont know how or even if it is possible also to fill the heading for this first column in the TreeView.

Comment: thanks joaquin, but can you please tell me how to allot the name of that empty column as well? thanks for your help:)

Comment: tree.heading('#0', text="First Column Heading"

The above code would put a heading to the first column.

Answer (score 2):

```py
tree.column("#0", width = 0, stretch = "no")
```

With that, you can get rid of the first column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
tree['show'] = ''
```